# Matrix norms for time varying matrices?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, products

So far, I have learned matrix norms for constant matrices, e.g.

$$\left\|A\right\|_1 = \max_{1\leq j\leq n}\sum_{i=1}^m\left|a_{ij}\right|$$

and norms of time dependent vectors, e.g.

$$\left\|\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)\right\|_2 = \sqrt{\int_{t_0}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^n\left|x_i\left(t\right)\right|^2}$$

Is there a norm defined for time varying matrices, e.g. $\left\|A\left(t\right)\right\|_1$, $\left\|A\left(t\right)\right\|_2$, and $\left\|A\left(t\right)\right\|_\infty$, whether it be integral or just a "product" e.g. $A^T\left(t\right)A\left(t\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

$A(t)$ is a matrix in terms of $t$. We can define

$$\|A(t)\|_1=\max_{1 \le j \le n}\sum_{i=1}^m|a_{ij}(t)|$$

and it will be a function of $t$. Similarly for the other norms.

Comment: Just to be complete, you can also integrate or take the $\mathrm{sup}$ of these time-varying norms to obtain a true norm on the space of time-varying matrices. I don't think these have any specific name or notation though

Comment: Got it, is there an integral definition of the norm by any chance?

Comment: hmmm integral over which variable?

Comment: I meant to say, is there an integral definition of the matrix norm with respect to time, just like there is for a time-dependent vector?

Comment: @whpowell96 can you write down the explicit formula?

Comment: Applying any integral norm to the function $\|A(t)\|$ will generate a norm. For instance, $\int_0^\infty\|A(t)\|dt$ or $\left(\int_0^\infty\|A(t)\|^2dt\right)^{1/2}$ for any choice of matrix norm $\|A\|$

Comment: assuming your timespan is $(0,\infty)$ obviously

Comment: @whpowell96 Ah I get it, you basically do the matrix norm as usual, but this becomes the integrand